# How to copy random files to a directory

Tags: shell-script, file-copy, random

First of all it isn't a homework. I just don't want to dig through a bunch of manuals and learn to program shell from A-Z to do this one thing.

I have a folder `/mnt/hdd/files` with lots of subfolders where i store files and would like to select and copy files randomly to let's say `/mnt/hdd/temp/1`

Is there a way to select and copy files until the folder `/mnt/hdd/temp/1` reaches a given size? (like 5 or 10Gbytes)

The average filesize is around 10mbyte so it'd be cool just to tell the command (script/batch?) the number of files (1000) to select randomly as well.

There are no duplicates and there is only one filetype in the dir tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it, assuming filenames don't have embedded newlines:

```
#! /bin/sh
dest=/mnt/hdd/temp/1
cd /mnt/hdd/files
find . -type f | \
    shuf -n 1000 | \
    while [ $(du -ks "$dest" | awk '{ print $1 }') -lt 10485760 ] && IFS= read -r fn; do
        cp "$fn" "$dest"
    done
```

This will copy random files from `/mnt/hdd/files` to `/mnt/hdd/temp/1` as long as the `du` size of the destination is less than 10 GB, but not more than 1000 files.

Comment: perfect thank you again. (oh. not again bc. someone who gave -1 edited my original question, deleting all of my sweet politeness out of it. congrats) Satō thank you, thank you, thank you. :)